# MySQL Script to delete certain rows from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
ID | FK_1 | FK_2 | MONTH | STATE

12  171     26      4   APPROVED
13  171     26      4   SUPER_APPROVED
14  56      32      4   APPROVED
15  45      34      4   SUPER_APPROVED
16  45      34      4   APPROVED
17  22      65      4   REJECTED
```

I need to remove duplicate rows so that there is only one row with each possible combination of FOREIGN_KEY_1, FOREIGN_KEY_2 and MONTH.

If there are two rows for that combination (such as row ids 12 & 13 or 15 & 16 above) I want to only keep the row that has the state SUPER_APPROVED.

After the script has been run I would expect the following data to be in the table (based on example data above):

```
ID | FK_1 | FK_2 | MONTH | STATE

13  171     26      4   SUPER_APPROVED
14  56      32      4   APPROVED
15  45      34      4   SUPER_APPROVED
17  22      65      4   REJECTED
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything thus far?  Please show your efforts so we can show improvements to your approach

Comment: Thats why is better to store data as state in numeric values. Get Max() or Min() is much easier than filter rows by values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to generate a list of the rows you want to keep.  Here is a query that does that:

```
      select FK_1, FK_2, MONTH,
             coalesce(min(case when state = 'SUPER_APPROVED' then id end),
                      min(id)
                     ) as id
      from table t
      group by FK_1, FK_2, MONTH;
```

Note that when there is 1 row for the combination, then the id for that row is in `id`.  Otherwise, it follows your rules of preferring the `SUPER_APPROVED` row.

You can use this for a `delete` by using `left outer join`:

```
delete t
    from table t left outer join
         (select FK_1, FK_2, MONTH,
                 coalesce(min(case when state = 'SUPER_APPROVED' then id end),
                          min(id)
                         ) as id
          from table t
          group by FK_1, FK_2, MONTH
         ) as tokeep
         on t.id = tokeep.id
    where tokeep.id is null;
```

Comment: @PiX06 . . . `table` was just meant to be a generic place holder for your table name.